# how to solve error - #1022 - Can't write; duplicate key in table 'Lives_in'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image]

NEED HELP PLEASE
I Want to make 3 things (id, cust_id, add_id) as primary key
and cust_id and add_id as the foreign key

Comment: Recommend for your next question a) include SQL as text. b) include error message also as text. c) NEVER USE ALL CAPS (no-one likes being yelled at) d) 'need help please" isn't needed. This is a help site, so yes, questions are expected and being explict just seems desperate (and is less likely to get a quick anser). Welcome to SO.

Comment: Your error message does not match provided screenshot with the code. If the table exists it'd dropped. If it cannot be dropped you'd receive another error message. If it not exists or dropped successfully then the code cannot produce shown error message.

Comment: How can HELP (why is this in capitals?) be give is you do not provide the complete TEXT that you are sending, + the complete error that you are receiving. It is not logical that a `CREATE TABLE` statement is producing an `Cant write; duplicate key` error

Comment: Constraint name specifying is fake for PRIMARY KEY - it will be ignored, and pre-defined `'PRIMARY'` will be used.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely you already have a constraint with the name iduser or idcategory in your database. Just rename the constraints if so.

Constraints must be unique for the entire database, not just for the specific table you are creating/altering.

To find out where the constraints are currently in use you can use the following query:

```
SELECT `TABLE_SCHEMA`, `TABLE_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`
WHERE `CONSTRAINT_NAME` IN (<name of the constraints errored>);
```

Comment: Please change constraint name in line 6 and 7.

Comment: The most likely is that this is not an answer to the problem, because the problem is unclear.

Comment: thanks, Amit. I have made the change and @luuk you mostly error #1022 means that you already have constraint with the same name and this will give an idea if there's is 1.

Comment: *The most likely you already have a constraint with the name ... in your database.* If so then the error #1826 `Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'constraint name'` is generated, not #1022.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help.. I managed to do it.  This is my improved code. ..............DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Lives_in;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Lives_in(
id int(5) NOT NULL,
cust_id int(5) NOT NULL,
add_id int(5) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT Lives_in_pk_id_custid_add_id PRIMARY KEY (id,cust_id,add_id),
CONSTRAINT Lives_in_fk_custid FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES Customer (cust_id),
CONSTRAINT Lives_in_fk_addid FOREIGN KEY (add_id) REFERENCES Address(add_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;